# Does sequelize support SQL Server views?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on a project that I need to define a model from SQL Server views. Is it possible to define a model from views according to not to use table joins and decrease complexities.

Comment: Have you posted this question on https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can point a Sequelize model at a view, rather than a table at least for SELECT statements (e.g. `model.findAll()`)   I doubt that `model.sync()` would work against a view, but haven't tested.  IIRC, some databases allow INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE against views in limited cases) and in those limited cases you **might** be able to use `model.create()`, `model.update()` or `model.delete()` also.

Comment: I used Sequelize-Auto and it generates a model from view and successfully worked with SELECT statement. I didn't expect to work with statements other than SELECT and my idea was using views for just SELECT statement.

Comment: It's possible and it'll work, the only problem is it'll be slower than reading an actual table. So, what I did is, I copied the data from the view into a table. The view & the table is recreated every time there's a create, update, or delete operation in the source table of the view.

Answer (score 0):

sequelize.sync() creates the models assuming that you only want to work with tables and tries to create a table when you actually want a view... as per the example below
[Error message when the view already exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3eNa.png)
In OBJECT_ID('V_Funds','U') 'U' is for Table.(cf. image)

So forget about using sequelize.sync() and just use Sequelize-Auto (as per the comments above). Then just run a simple .bat or .cmd such as the one below and all is done for you automatically

rem recreate the various models
node node_modules\sequelize-auto\bin\sequelize-auto -h localhost -d XXXX -e mssql -u sa -x PASSWORD -c "./config.json" -o "./../server/src/models"